# Synonym for non-psychological calculation

Tags: synonyms, psychology

What would be a synonym or more apropos phrase for a non-pyschological calculation?

For example, imagine a general knows that the best strategy, objectively speaking, might be to defend the low roads and byways, but he knows that the opposing general likes to attack at strong points, so instead he fortifies his hilltop positions. In one case, there is a calculation that ignores the human dimension, and in the other the general includes information about the psychology of his opponent. In the latter case we have a "psychological strategy", but what should the strategy be called that does not include human psychology?

Answer (score 1):

Since the plan in question is based on reasoning from first principles rather than the specific case, it might be called an [a priori](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/a-priori) strategy.

This is certainly used at the bridge table, to describe a plan based on mathematical probabilities rather than "If she had the Ace she would have led it: so it must be on the other side". (The latter is more successful, which confuses mathematicians.)

Answer (score 0):

a **heterodox strategy** will ignore the conventional factors, including what the opposing general might be contemplating.

> - [**heterodox**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/heterodox) - "contrary to or different from an acknowledged standard or a traditional form"

e.g.

- a heterodox view
- a heterodox approach
- a heterodox theory
- a heterodox design
- a heterodox alternative